# Error al usar SUM en MySQL y mostrar por grupos

Tags: mysql

El problema es el siguiente: Tengo una consulta la cual saca toda la información de un profesor incluyendo con sus dos sueldos, los cuales tengo que sumar y mostrarlos por calendario, anteriormente en otra pregunta me respondieron que podía realizar la suma por grupos, es decir, yo utilizo el `SUM(tabla1+tabla2)` y hago un `GROUP` por calendario pero los numero se van muy arriba y no entiendo el porque.

Esta es la consulta que me arroja correctamente los valores sin agruparlos:

```
SELECT  profesores.nombre_profe ,
        profesores.apellido_paterno ,
        profesores.apellido_materno ,
        puestos.puesto1 ,
        puestos.puesto2 ,
        (sueldos.sueldo1 + sueldos.sueldo2) AS total ,
        calendarios.nombre_calendario
FROM    sueldos
        INNER JOIN profesores ON sueldos.profesores_id = profesores.id
        INNER JOIN puestos ON puestos.profesores_id = profesores.id
        INNER JOIN calendarios ON sueldos.calendarios_id = calendarios.id
WHERE   profesores.id = 378;
```

En esta consulta no uso el SUM ya que da numeros muy exagerados y el resultado de esta es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te muestra el total y los calendarios, lo que yo quiero hacer es que se muestren agrupados por calendario. Es decir, que se sumen todos los totales de dicho calendario.

Esta es mi consulta donde agrupo por calendario y me da valores grandes:

```
SELECT  profesores.nombre_profe ,
        profesores.apellido_paterno ,
        profesores.apellido_materno ,
        puestos.puesto1 ,
        puestos.puesto2 ,
        SUM(sueldos.sueldo1 + sueldos.sueldo2) AS total ,
        calendarios.nombre_calendario
FROM    sueldos
        INNER JOIN profesores ON sueldos.profesores_id = profesores.id
        INNER JOIN puestos ON puestos.profesores_id = profesores.id
        INNER JOIN calendarios ON sueldos.calendarios_id = calendarios.id
WHERE   profesores.id = 378
GROUP BY calendarios.nombre_calendario;
```

Resultado: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin que los resultados se vayan muy alto, realmente no se la razón por la cual se van tan arriba los resultados.

Comment: ¿Podrías rellenar unos cuantos datos en un https://www.db-fiddle.com/ para poder probar la consulta con más facilidad? Conozco el problema y sé cómo solucionarlo, pero es probable que deba hacer una consulta anidada porque es probable que no se pueda realizar únicamente con `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Viendo esto: `(sueldos.sueldo1 + sueldos.sueldo2) AS total...` y luego esto: `INNER JOIN profesores ON sueldos.profesores_id = profesores.id` **sospecho** que el problema viene por la forma en que tienes tu relación **profesores->sueldos**, al parecer un profesor tendría dos tipos de sueldos, pero es muy probable que haya un problema en esa relación. Si las relaciones están bien creo que podrías obtener tu resultado final en una sola consulta sin ningún tipo de problemas, agrupando como mejor te convenga.

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es remplazar INNER JOIN por LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos buscar la solución partiendo de esta consulta que te funciona correctamente:

```
SELECT  profesores.nombre_profe ,
        profesores.apellido_paterno ,
        profesores.apellido_materno ,
        puestos.puesto1 ,
        puestos.puesto2 ,
        (sueldos.sueldo1 + sueldos.sueldo2) AS total ,
        calendarios.nombre_calendario
FROM    sueldos
        INNER JOIN profesores ON sueldos.profesores_id = profesores.id
        INNER JOIN puestos ON puestos.profesores_id = profesores.id
        INNER JOIN calendarios ON sueldos.calendarios_id = calendarios.id
WHERE   profesores.id = 378
```

La podemos usar como consulta interna en una consulta anidada de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT  nombre_profe,
        apellido_paterno,
        apellido_materno,
        puesto1,
        puesto2,
        SUM(total) total,
        nombre_calendario
FROM (
    SELECT  profesores.nombre_profe nombre_profe,
            profesores.apellido_paterno apellido_paterno,
            profesores.apellido_materno apellido_materno,
            puestos.puesto1 puesto1,
            puestos.puesto2 puesto2,
            (sueldos.sueldo1 + sueldos.sueldo2) total ,
            calendarios.nombre_calendario nombre_calendario
    FROM    sueldos
            INNER JOIN profesores ON sueldos.profesores_id = profesores.id
            INNER JOIN puestos ON puestos.profesores_id = profesores.id
            INNER JOIN calendarios ON sueldos.calendarios_id = calendarios.id
    WHERE   profesores.id = 378
) sc
GROUP BY sq.nombre_calendario
```

Donde la subconsulta (`sc`) contiene todos los datos que necesitas y la consulta externa los agrega de manera correcta.

Te dejo una prueba de concepto preparada online aquí:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pNKqKqL1BmgXa6fY9AXTUN/0

---

Pensaba que podría tratarse (me ha pasado) de un efecto secundario de cómo se resuelven las uniones de tablas, pero tras dedicarle algo más tiempo me doy cuenta que no es el caso.

Cuando tengas problemas agrupando o sumando valores puedes hacer caso de [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) que te permite mostrar en un campo adicional todo aquello que ha agrupado.

He reproducido tus dos primeras fechas completas (con los datos proporcionados en la imagen, si hubiera tenido más datos reales hubiera podido estar completamente seguro de cada consulta) en el siguiente enlace:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8RtDxQVrvSiHMu3VoThbGX/0

En el que ejecuto la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
SELECT profesores.nombre_profe ,
       profesores.apellido_paterno ,
       profesores.apellido_materno ,
       puestos.puesto1 ,
       puestos.puesto2 ,
       SUM(
         sueldos.sueldo1 + sueldos.sueldo2
       ) AS total,
       GROUP_CONCAT(
         '(',
         sueldos.sueldo1,
         '+',
         sueldos.sueldo2,
         ')'
       SEPARATOR ' + ') AS suma,
       calendarios.nombre_calendario
FROM   sueldos
       INNER JOIN profesores
         ON sueldos.profesores_id = profesores.id
       INNER JOIN puestos
         ON puestos.profesores_id = profesores.id
       INNER JOIN calendarios
         ON sueldos.calendarios_id = calendarios.id
WHERE
  profesores.id = 378
GROUP BY
  calendarios.nombre_calendario
```

Y el resultado ha sido:
[image: Resultado de la consulta SQL]

Se puede comprobar que están todos los datos y con copiar y pegar cada celda en una calculadora se comprueba que los resultados son correctos, por lo que te recomiendo que uses esta consulta en tu base de datos para depurar qué es lo que se está sumando de más.

*Reflexión:*

¿Te ocurre eso que comentas cuando buscas más de un profesor o no pones restricción de éste en el `WHERE`? Si es así se sumarán los sueldos de los demás profesores: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8RtDxQVrvSiHMu3VoThbGX/1

En ese caso también deberás agrupar por el profesor. Yo siempre recomiendo agrupar por un campo único (clave primaria a ser posible) por lo que agregaré `profesores.id`: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8RtDxQVrvSiHMu3VoThbGX/2

Por último, este código no funciona en MySQL 5.7 o superior si no se usan absolutamente todos los campos no agregados (con el `SUM`, por ejemplo) en el `GROUP BY`: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8RtDxQVrvSiHMu3VoThbGX/3

Por lo que quizá sea recomendable que, si no vas a hacer uso de esos campos (quieres el total por profesor, y no el total por profesor y tipo de puesto), no los pongas en el `SELECT`.